# validating array values from fgetcsv

Tags: php

im checking a csv file if some data is missing,

the header that is the array contains a string which needs to be matched.

first i need to check to see the first array contains Date,time,L1,L2,L3

second  from the second array it should always check the date and time format .

Below is the code i tried

```
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    $current_line="";
    echo "<pre>";
    $i=0;
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $current_line = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

        print_r($current_line);
        if(@in_array('', $current_line) )
        {
            throw new Exception('Some data is missing');
        }
        else {
            $line_of_text[] = $current_line;
            //print_r($line_of_text);
        }
        $i++;
    }

    fclose($file_handle);
```

printin the $current_line gives me this

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Date
    [1] => Time
    [2] => L1
    [3] => L2
    [4] => L3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 10/31/2013
    [1] => 13:53:35
    [2] => 39.8
    [3] => 36.2
    [4] => 39.6
)

Array
(
    [0] => 10/31/2013
    [1] => 13:53:40
    [2] => 39.8
    [3] => 36.6
    [4] => 39.7
)
```

Comment: Where is your code that validates the date and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
$a_cols_sample = array('Date', 'time', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3');
$a_cols = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
if (!($a_cols && count($a_cols) == 5 && $a_cols === $a_cols_sample)) return;
$result = array();
while (($a_vals = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024)) !== false) {
    if (count($a_vals) != 5) continue;
    list($date, $time, , , ) = $a_vals;
    if (date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $date) === false) continue;
    if (date_create_from_format('h:i:s', $time) === false) continue;
    $result[] = $a_vals;
}
print_r($result);
fclose($file_handle);
```